# Framework/software for dynamic WPS creation

Tags: open-source-gis, java, wps, framework, software-recommendations

We have some specific EO data processing facility and are about to provide an access to one using WPS-based interface. The are plenty of solutions for the task. However, it is hard to find one that meets our requirements:

1. Ability to deploy services (or processes) automatically (without UI)
2. Ability to deploy service without rebuilding from sources or restarting the container. I.e. deployment of one service/process shouldn't affect others.
3. Open/free license

There also some Java frameworks that allow to implement WPS service right in the app, but they are poorly documented.

Could anyone recommend something that suits our needs?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the service? That may make it easier to suggest an appropriate alternative for your needs. You can just update your question (click "edit" above) with this information.

Comment: I have added some info about the context, hope this helps (Thanks for the edits).

Comment: [Zoo project](http://www.zoo-project.org/) seems to meet your requirements. Check [the documentation](http://www.zoo-project.org/docs/).

Comment: For software recommendations I recommend the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is a *very* specific software to search for on the common place

Answer (score 1):

Deegree WPS could be used as a container, where custom WPS workspace could be deployed via REST API: [Deploy new WPS at deegree without UI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58518/deploy-new-wps-at-deegree-without-ui)