# Deploy new WPS at deegree without UI

Tags: wps, deployment, deegree

How can I deploy a custom WPS on deegree without using the UI?

Comment: Not sure try this http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.2.0/html/webservices.html#anchor-configuration-wps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment could be done with REST API: http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.2.1/html/restapi.html

The service iself could be created according to:
http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.2.1/html/webservices.html#web-processing-service-wps